# Aligning divs underneath each other

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div id="container" class="container">

    <div id="menu-top">
        <div class="top-menu">
             <div class="top-menu-buttons">
                <button class="button button-icon ion-minus-circled"></button>
                <span>{{amount}}</span>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-plus-circled"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="classic" class="classic">
        <div id="classic-img" class="classic-img">
            <img ng-src="{{image.filtered}}" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu-bottom">
        <div class="bottom-menu">
            <div class="bottom-menu-buttons">
                <button class="button button-icon ion-eye"></button>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-refresh"></button>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-crop"></button>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-android-options"></button>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-social-tumblr"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this css:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.classic {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("../img/frames/postcard_00.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.classic-img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 6%;
    left: 5%;
}

.classic img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.top-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.top-menu-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-menu-buttons .button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

.top-menu-buttons span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

.bottom-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

.bottom-menu-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.bottom-menu-buttons .button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The result i want to have:

[image]

The result i got from above code:

[image]

My css is designed so that the blue content is under the red (top menu) and the green (bottom menu) is under the blue content. I cant find the mistake i made.

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: Which part of the styles do you believe should put the bottom menu at the bottom currently?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the bottom menu be a footer flowing normally under the page content? No fixed positioning or anything? Just a normal footer? Also, please make a fiddle or a snippet.

Comment: a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jfj3syvt/. yes, no fixed positining.

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/jfj3syvt/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/jfj3syvt/1/)

`position:absolute` was the culprit.

You have to remove that from `.classic-img` and `.classic-img img`. Also, remove `height: 100%;` from `.classic-img img`. So the changed CSS would be as below

```
.classic-img {
    display: block;
    /* position: absolute; */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 6%;
    left: 5%;
}

.classic-img img {
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need an absolute position for both the image & the image container, if that is really necessary, you need to give the parent #classic a height.

Or you can remove the absolute positioning for the image & the image container like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jfj3syvt/2/)

Or if you want the image to be fluid, just set it width to 100% instead of absolute positioning

```
.classic-img img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give style rule `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` to the `.bottom-menu element`. This will bring the `.bottom menu` at the bottom of page.
This will hopefully work for you.

Comment: but thats not what i want. i want it to be under the blue content. it can happen that the content must be scrolled and i dont want the bottom menu to cover the blue content.

Comment: Well it wont cover the blue content at all. If the position is set to be `fixed` only then it will cover the blue content.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle.